# Multiple labels for multiple data sets using Charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this Bar Chart with two data Sets.  I'm trying to show the number of clicks for each application for Employees and Students.

[image]

Each bar represents an app.  As you can see, for employees, I have app A,B,C,D, etc, and for students, I drew in app 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

The array employee_app_names contains the label values for Employees.  The array student_app_names contains the label values for Students.

How can I have multiple labels for multiple data sets in a bar graph so that the bar graph looks like the image I've attached?

Here's my Code:

```
eval("employee_app_names  = [" + response.employee_app_names + "]");
eval("employee_app_clicks = [" + response.employee_app_clicks + "]");
eval("student_app_names  = [" + response.student_app_names + "]");
eval("student_app_clicks = [" + response.student_app_clicks + "]");
var ctx = $("#" + reportName).get(0).getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = 800;
ctx.canvas.height = 250;
var data = {
  labels: employee_app_names, // THIS IS A,B,C,D,E,ETC
  datasets: [{
      data: employee_app_clicks,
      label: "Employees/Aux",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(86, 88, 135,0.7)"
    },
    {
      data: student_app_clicks,
      label: "Students",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(117, 196, 124,0.7)"
    }
  ]

}
myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: data,
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: response.title
  },
  scaleShowValues: true,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false
      }
    }]
  }
}
});
}, "json");
```

Comment: what you want to achieve

Comment: The Image show what I would like to achieve.  A label for each bar.

Comment: at the bottom of each bar?

Comment: Yes, at the bottom of each bar. Using two datasets as shown above.

Comment: When you pass the labels on this line `labels: employee_app_names`, does it only accept strings, or can you pass it HTML?